# How to pass JSON data to a modal in angular 2

Tags: arrays, angular, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to pop up a modal in angular 2 that will display a list of people.  The source of the list is a JSON file.  I think the data is not being properly bound to the table in the modal. I am new to angular 2 and am not sure what I am missing.

Service to read JSON file:
  returns-json-array-service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ReturnsJsonArrayService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getPeople(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.request('./people.json')
      .do( res => console.log('HTTP response:', res))
      .map(res => res.json().payload)
      .do(console.log);
    //.map(res => res.json());

    /*return this.http.get('./people.json')
     .map((res:Response) => res.json())
     .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));*/
  }

}
```

SAmple json file: people.json

```
 {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "David Martinez Ros",
    "email": "info@davidmartinezros.com",
    "age": "33"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Paco Roberto Corto",
    "email": "paco.roberto.corto@gmail.com",
    "age": "51"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Silvia Elegante i Latina",
    "email": "silvia.elegante.latina@gmail.com",
    "age": "30"
  }
]
```

modal-component.ts

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

import {NgbModal, NgbActiveModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ReturnsJsonArrayService } from './returns-json-array.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-content',
  providers: [ReturnsJsonArrayService],
  template: `
<div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
  <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
<div class="modal-body" *ngFor="let person of peopleData | async" >
  <p>One fine body…</p>
  <table border=1>
 <tr>
 <td>
  <h3>Id: {{ person.id }}</h3>
</td>
<td>
  <h3>name: {{ person.name }}</h3>
</td>
<td>
  <h3>email: {{ person.email }}</h3>
</td>
<td>
  <h3>age: {{ person.age }}</h3>
</td>
<td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Submit</button>
 </div>
`
})
export class NgbdModalContent {
  @Input() name;
  @Input() peopleData: Observable<Array<any>>;

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal,private peopleService: ReturnsJsonArrayService) {
    this.peopleData = this.peopleService.getPeople();
    console.log("AppComponent.data:" + this.peopleData);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-component',
  templateUrl: './modal-component.html'
})
export class NgbdModalComponent {
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  open() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'Barb' ;
    console.log("Peopledatra on open():" + modalRef.componentInstance.peopleData);

  }
}
```

modal-component.html

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="open()">Assign</button>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What is the current behavior and what is the expected behavior? ***I think the data is not being properly bound to the table in the modal*** doesn't tell us much ;)

Answer (score 0):

`this.peopleService.getPeople()` returns an observable which is cold to activate it and make it hot you must add a subscribe `this.peopleService.getPeople().subscribe()` the subscribe will take a success method as the first argument like so:

```
this.peopleService.getPerople().subscribe(
  (json) => {
  // do something here with the json
  }
)
```

Once the json is returned you can set it to a property within your components scope like so:

```
this.peopleService.getPerople().subscribe(
  (json) => {
    this.json = json;
  }
)
```

That property will then be accessible with in the components template.

Comment: Just briefly looking at the code... OP is using the async pipe so this should not be the issue.

Comment: Yes but usually when you use pipe it is not on an observable that automatically unsubscribes following the return of the first result. As the observables returned by the http service do.